# Calling A Function on a Nested Resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, nested-resources

I have a music app that I'm building. I want to set it up in such a way that an artist can  upload a music file but it will not show up on the index page until an admin approves the file to make sure it is not spam. I have nested the songs resource under the users resource and called approve on member but I get the error below. How do I call a method on nested if it is being called by an admin user who did not create song.

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in SongsController#approve
Couldn't find Song with id=1
app/controllers/songs_controller.rb:35:in `approve'
```

The song id is actually 13.

In the songs controller the approve function:

```
def approve
    @song = Song.find(params[:id])
    @song.accept
    #UserMailer.invitation_confirmation.deliver
    redirect_to :back, :only_path => true, :success => "Sent approval for #{@song.title} to #{@song.user.name} at #{@song.user.email}." 
  end
```

In the users controller show action I have

```
def show
    @songs = Song.all 
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end
```

In the routes file:

```
resources :users do 
    resources :songs do 
      get 'approve', on: :member
      get 'decline', on: :member
    end
  end
```

And in the view for the admin dashboard I have

```
<% if @user.admin? %>
    <% @songs.each do |song| %>
        <%= image_tag song.artwork_url(:thumb) if song.artwork? %>
        <h4>Title</h4><p><%= song.title %></p>
        <h4>Album</h4><p><%= song.album %></p>
        <p><%= song.current_state %></p>
        <%= link_to "Approve", approve_user_song_path(song) %> | 
        <%= link_to "Decline", decline_user_song_path(song) %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Where did `@songs` come from in your admin dashboard view? Is it a collection from the `Song` ActiveRecord?

Comment: yes it is the index of all the songs created by artists on the website. I forgot to add the code from the users controller showing this, but it has been added now.

Comment: I don't see yet why this shouldn't work. In your view (where you show the title, album, etc), did you add an extra test field that shows the `id` to confirm that it's 13 in this case? (e.g., `<p>Id = <%= song.id %></p>`)

Comment: @mbratch, I just did that and it is showing the right song id. The problem I believe is that since it is a nested resource `approve_user_song GET /users/:user_id/songs/:id/approve(.:format)`, the `:user_id` is being substituted wtih the admin `user_id` so it cant find the song to call the approve method on, since the admin did not create the song

Comment: In this case, then, you should be seeing a path of `/users/1/songs/13/approve`, but you're seeing `/users/1/songs/1/approve`?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Since it is a nested resource as I mentioned, the `approve_user_song_path` is `/users/:user_id/songs/:id/approve(.:format)` so it is looking for the `user_id`, it passes the admin's `user_id` as the user's `id` but since the admin is not the user who created the song, there is an error. To solve this I passed in both the user and song as arguments into the approve and decline method.

So in the show template it looks like this.

```
<% @songs.each do |song| %>
        <%= image_tag song.artwork_url(:thumb) if song.artwork? %>
        <h4>Title</h4><p><%= song.title %></p>
        <h4>Album</h4><p><%= song.album %></p>
        <p><%= song.id%></p>
        <%= song.user_id %>
      <%= song.current_state %>
        <%= link_to "Approve", approve_user_song_path(song.user, song) %> | 
        <%= link_to "Decline", decline_user_song_path(song.user, song) %>
    <% end %>
```

This got it working, thanks @mbratch for your comments, I hope this helps someone else new to rails like me. :)

Comment: And thanks to the guys who edited my initial question, I should have read it for grammatical errors